# How do i reduce the number of for loops in my code

Tags: c

How do i make this code more efficient for larger numbers of the size 10^9. I don't think i can reduce the number of for loops in this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

int e;
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
for(e=0;e<t;e++){
        int x,y;
        scanf("%d",&x);
        scanf("%d",&y);
        int sum=0;
        int j,k,i;
        for(j=x;j<y;j++){
            for(k=j+1;k<=y;k++){
                int max=1;
                for(i=2;i<=j;i++)
                    if((j%i==0)&&(k%i==0))
                    max=i;
                sum+=max;
            }
        }
        printf("%d",sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your code do? if you need a better algorithm, we'll need a proper problem description.

Comment: Hey, it's 2014, only sixty years after C style like that became obsolete. You can declare your variables where you need them, not leak them all over the place, e.g. `for (int e = 0; e < t; ++e)` etc.

Comment: I want to build an algo for calculating the sum of all the possible greatest common divisors in a inclusive range entered by the user.

Comment: @KerrekSB It didn't became obsolete at all. I still prefer declaring variables only at beginning of the scope, because that is a lot more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Euclid greatest common divisor algorithm is the most historical and probably the most efficient algorithm for calculating gcd, it may help you for reducing the number of for loops.

Answer (score 0):

If the input size is very huge as you said and you can do some checks for some numbers manually before entering the loop and that may reduce the number loops by 10 times or so before entering.
(Even if in range checking for small numbers will be useful as 2*x == x*2)

Also may be multiples of 10's 5's and so on can be negated in the first loop.

Lot of better algorithm are available on net search a bit more if you cant come with your own

Try adding few comments in your code so it could be more understandable by lesser effort from the people helping you.

NOTE:- I didn't go through your code completely nor most off the people would do.**ADD COMMENTS**